# Using js/jquery to loop through a list of html files to load in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've got a set of HTML files that I would like to loop through via an iframe and I'm not quite sure how to set up the javascript since I have virtually no experience with it. Here's my attempt at getting this to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = 'utf-8'>
    <title>Sankey Plot Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe src = "plot1.html" width = 100% height = 100% id = "sankey"></iframe>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var selector = document.getElementById('sankey'),
        var delay_sec = 1,
        var num = 0,
        var len = 2;
        setInterval(function() {
          num = (num === len) ? 0 : num;
          selector.src = "plot" + num + ".html";
          num++;
        }, delay_sec * 50);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code above was haphazardly thrown together via other answers I saw on SO. I assumed this would be something simple like (pseudo-code):

```
<script>
  var counter = 0;
  for (i = 0, i < eternity, i++) {
    counter++;
    counter = (counter === 2) ? 0 : counter;
    var source = "plot" + counter + ".html";
    $("#sankey").load(source);
    sleep(2 seconds);
  }
</script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Side question not related to main question: Why, in the first block of code I have, are there commas instead of semicolons in the js code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// You should also only do DOM manipulation after DOM ready and the
//   easiest way to do that is to pass a function directly to jQuery
//   like so
$(function() {
    // I'm just guessing you mean to use jQuery since you included it
    //  #sankeyis the CSS syntax for selecting an element with the
    //  ID 'sankey' and jQuery uses CSS syntax for selecting elements
    var selector = $('#sankey');
    var delay_sec = 10;
    var num = 0,
        len = 2;
    setInterval(function() {
        num = (num === len) ? 0 : num;
        //this is how you set an attribute on a jQuery selector
        selector.attr('src', "plot" + num + ".html");
        num++;
    //the second argument to setTimeout/setInterval is in milliseconds
    }, delay_sec * 1000);
});
```

You can define variables in a sort of list format in JavaScript like this:

```
var i = 0,
    j = 1, 
    k = 2;
```

That's equivalent to:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 1;
var z = 2;
```

This is a syntax error:

```
var i = 0, var j = 1;
```

Comment: That works, thank you! One last question: Why do you have to add the second set of `()` after you close the function?

Comment: That calls the function immediately after it's created, which you don't _have to_ do, but it's a common idiom used to create a scope that doesn't leak values into the global scope, which is important to preventing multiple scripts from stomping on each others' vars.  I like to think of it as a namespace, if you're familiar with other languages that have that concept.

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Is that to imply that jquery is only called when DOM is ready? And passing the function directly to jquery simply requires passing the jquery indicator `$` in front of the function?

Comment: $ is the function that jQuery defines by default in the global scope. $(function(){}) passes a function to that function. jQ will then call that function when the DOMready event fires, which signals that the DOM is ready to be manipulated (like changing attributes on an iframe, for example). It's just safer to always register functionality that manipulates the DOM to run like that, but putting the script block at the bottom will have approximately the same effect because of the way the page is parsed.